# Unexpected output of LINQ Where when filtering by Contains(variable)

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "g";
            string[] color = { "greena", "browna", "bluea" };
            var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
            Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
            s = "a";
            query = query.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
            Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

I think it will output should be following because when `query=color.where(c=>c.contains("g"))` I think it should contain `{greena}`, so when on second query runs `query = query.where(c=>c.contains("a");` then it only matched green only so when counted is 1:

```
1
1
```

But the output after running the code is

```
1
3
```

Why second filtering matches all elements (even if only one contains "g" and second query should have just looked at one)?

Comment: You're question is confusing, your result is correct (1, 3). Why do you believe it should be (1, 1)?

Comment: I think like this, when `query=color.where(c=>c.contains("g"))` I think it should contain {greena}, so when on second query.query.where(c=>c.contains("a"); then it only matched green only so when counted is 1

Comment: Why would you expect that output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're being bitten by a captured variable:

```
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
```

Lifts `s` into a closure and reads the value of `s` *at the time of execution*. In this case, this happens *after* you re-assign `s` to something else.

What you end up having as your query is:

```
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).Where(c => c.Contains(s));
```

Rather than what you're probably expecting:

```
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains("g")).Where(c => c.Contains("a"));
```

This will produce the result you're expecting:

```
string s = "g";
string[] color = { "greena", "browna", "bluea" };
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
var b = "a";
query = query.Where(c => c.Contains(b));
Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); // <-- This is where the entire expression is evaluated
```

Comment: when `query = query.Where(c => c.Contains(s));` then the end up query is this? `var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).Where(c => c.Contains(s));`

Comment: @Calvin That's correct, yes.

Comment: but query is containing greena after first .where(), but why when second  query.query().  not searching on {"greena"} but it used `var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).Where(c => c.Contains(s));`?

Comment: @Calvin Because the first time you print it, the expression is evaluated with one result. Then, you change the value of `s`. When you print the count, the expression will be evaluated *again* - receiving the new value of `s` to filter on. The second assignment of `query` has no impact on this.  If you remove the `query = query.Where(c => c.Contains(s));` line, you'll see the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: @Rob, okay, I understand tq for the explanation.

Comment: I drop this here for who read this,there is a reference on how it works on iolympian answer's comment

Answer (score 3):

The first line for the query:

```
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
```

Does not put the results in the query. It generates a query that has a source of string[] color with a predicate (filter) of .Contains(s).  This doesn't get executed until .Count() is executed.

What this means is on the next execution of query.Contains() it's working on the original source of items.  So, while you would expect the first result:

```
s = "g";
color.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
```

to return a count of 1 which is "greena", and then

```
s = "a";
query.Where(c => c.Contains(s)); //  Where query now contains only: "greena" and hence return 1 for a count
```

What's really happening is this:

```
s = "g";
string[] color = { "greena", "browna", "bluea" };
query = color;
Console.WriteLine(query.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).Count());
// Outputs 1 because g appears only in greena

s = "g";
// query still contains the original color list
Console.WriteLine(query.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).Count());   
// Outputs 3 because a appears in all three
```

In order to function as you are expecting you have to force the execution of the linq in the first query:

```
string s = "g";
string[] color = { "greena", "browna", "bluea" };
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s)).Select(x => x).ToArray();
// Notice the ToArray() -- it forces execution of the linq which returns the results, not the query itself.
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
s = "a";
var query2 = query.Select(x => x).Where(c => c.Contains(s));
Console.WriteLine(query2.Count());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: As an FYI, you can confirm what I'm saying by running the original code through a debugger and watching the source property on the query variable.

Comment: do you have some reference why it still use the original color list? and not query that has been filled with {"greena"} `when var query = color.Where(c=>Contains(s);`  `where s = "g"`

Comment: I'll post a reference, but link doesn't get executed against the data until certain commands. So, .Count() forces the link query to execute so it can count the results. But if you put: query = list.WHERE (c => c.contains("a") ; query = query.Where(c => c.contains("b"); query = query.Where(c => c.contains("c");   you don't end up with any results because at this point you've built a linq  query, you haven't executed it against the source list yet. To do that you have to run something like .Count(), .ToArray(), .ToList(), or other methods that execute the line and work on the results.

Comment: that means i cant use the query on the first .where() which contain "greena" to be counted on second time, but its evaluate the linq on var query that has builded?

Comment: Reference for what I'm talking about.  You are working on an iqueryable object, not a resultset. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Note that "What's really happening is this" is not what really happening in OP's code. Correct equivalent code is shown in Rob's answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41733726/477420 ( `color.Where().Where()`)

Comment: It was a simplistic answer to describe from a new programmers point of view what is happening. I didn't go into instantiation of an iqueryable object as well as th execution of the object against the dataset. That line was pseudo code for exemplary purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Your colors aren't spelled correctly.

Greena, browna, bluea all have the character 'a' in them. Your linq expression is working as intended.

Comment: it is intended.

Comment: If that's the case, linq will return all items where it can find an a. That gives you 3. Your code is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Because firstly you are looking for letter 'g', which only 'greena' contains. Afterwards, you change the value of `s = "a"` and then run a query and look for all words with letter 'a' in them, in this case all 3 of them have 'a', therefore you are getting 1 and 3 as an output. Everything is correct. Why are you intending to get 1 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

On the first part, it says, you query all colors with the letter g inside which is only 1, that's why it outputs 1:

```
string s = "g";
string[] color = { "greena", "browna", "bluea" };
var query = color.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
```

On the second part, it says, you query all colors which contains letter a inside which is every index on your array has letter a inside so it outputs 3:

```
 s = "a";
 query = query.Where(c => c.Contains(s));
 Console.WriteLine(query.Count());
```